# User Interaction with chain List Items

Tags: c#, list

I have the following List items and try to find out an algorithm which takes care of user interaction.

```
tableItems.Add (new TableItem() {Start=1000, End=4000});
tableItems.Add (new TableItem() {Start=4000, End=6000});
tableItems.Add (new TableItem() {Start=6000, End=8000});
```

For example in the list, if user changes the first item "End" value that affects also second list item's "Start" value. That has to match.  It is like a chain. Also, if user wants to change second item "Start" value, then the first item "End" value has to match as well.

What is effective way of solving this chain problem?

Comment: How could I cope with an algorithm to solve this chain list items?

Comment: Can't you use variables rather that strings and add them to the table. You only need two variables as start1 and end1. Where second item in the collection has a start value as End 1 (I would go with End1 + 1). Likewise if you change End2 (6000 in the example), it will affect to change row 3 start value which would be End2+1. Is this what you need?

Comment: Why don't you store just the "bounds"? If you'd store just 1000, 4000, 6000, 8000 (for example in `List<int>`), there would be no need to adjust the neighbours.

Comment: Could you please illustrate your comment as an answer to see clear picture?

Comment: How could you store the bounds?

Comment: @texas in the same way as you store the `TableItem`s. The `End` seems redundant to me, if it is the same as the `Start` of the next item.

Comment: `End` is relevant if there is only one item in the collection.

Comment: If you do not mind, you please provide as answer.

Comment: @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey not really. You could have 2 items (1000, 4000) in the collection. One for start, one for the end, so you have one "interval" (1000 to 4000) if you add another item (e.g. 6000), you will have 3 bounds, thus 2 intervals: (1000 to 4000 and 4000 to 6000)

Comment: @Matyas  Yeah that would work. Collection would always have to have a capping value like that.  Honestly, there are a few other areas where this particular question is going to break that your solution also solves (such as  inserting a nonsequential element in the middle.. just need to sort) +1 to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    var rangeManager = new RangeManager();
    rangeManager.SetRange(3, 6000, 9000);
    rangeManager.GetRange(3).Dump();
    rangeManager.SetRange(1, 500, 4000);
    rangeManager.GetRange(1).Dump();
}

public class RangeManager
{
    private List<int> _values;

    public RangeManager()
    {
        _values = new List<int> { 0, 1000, 4000, 6000, 8000 };
    }

    public Range GetRange(int index)
    {
        // TODO check for index out of range
        return new Range(_values[index], _values[index + 1]);
    }

    public void SetRange(int index, int start, int finish)
    {
        // TODO check for index out of range
        // TODO make sure start less than finish
        // TODO make sure start greater than previous value
        // TODO make sure finish less than next + 1 value
        _values[index] = start;
        _values[index + 1] = finish;
    }
}

public class Range
{
    public int Start { get; private set; }
    public int Finish { get; private set; }

    public Range(int start, int finish)
    {
        Start = start;
        Finish = finish;
    }
}
```

To understand what's going on here, start with the `Range` class. It is simply a holder for `Start` and `Finish`.

Next, look at the `RangeManager` class. It encapsulates the management of your chained ranges. It holds the values (range endpoints) in a list on integers (rather than a list of `Range` objects). This is a better way to store the data, because you no longer need to update neighboring objects when updating a range. Also, note that it's better to use integers than strings. The `RangeManager` class also has methods to help you manipulate and output your ranges.

Finally, look at the `Main` method. This shows an example of how to use the `RangeManager` and allows you to test whether it is working properly.